# Is the order of the result is the same when convert map to vector in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am working over a map using keys and vals, if I run the same code multiple time, will it always return the same collection considering order?  I tried (keys a), every time I run it (:c :b :a)
 returns. But want to confirm it ALWAYS returns the same.

```
(def a {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
(keys a)
(vals a)
```

Answer (score 3):

Not all Clojure maps will retain the order of entries. If you want to retain insertion order you would need to use clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap (produced by [array-map](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/array-map) or the map literal). Keep in mind that an array map is intended for a small number of entries and that certain operations will perform poorly with a larger number of entries.

If you want to maintain sorted order (but not insertion order) then you would need to use a sorted map (produced by [sorted-map](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sorted-map)).

A hash map (produced by [hash-map](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/hash-map)) gives no guarantees in respect of order.

Clojure's map literal produces an array map.

```
(class {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
; => clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap

; zipmap's returned map type will vary depending on the number of entries in the map 
(class (zipmap (range 0 1000) (range 1000 2000)))
; => clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap

(class (zipmap (range 1 3) (range 3 5)))
; => clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap

(class (sorted-map :a 1 :b 2 :c 3))
; => clojure.lang.PersistentTreeMap

(class (hash-map :a 1 :b 2 :c 3))
; => clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap
```

You would also need to be careful not to inadvertently change the map type, e.g.:

```
(class (into {} (map #(vector (key %) (inc (val %))) (sorted-map :a 1))))
; => clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
```

It is best not to rely on the order of entries in a map, so if you can think of a way to achieve what you want without relying on the order of entries in a map then you should strongly consider it.

Answer (score 2):

Maps are unordered and no order is guaranteed. So, don't write code that depends on it, even with array-map.

Any particular instance of a map is guaranteed to return you entries in the same order (via seq, keys, vals, etc) such that (keys m) and (vals m) "match up".

If you need an ordered map, try https://github.com/amalloy/ordered.